# Vba Excel Is it possible to select a value out of userform that is showing parts of a table?

Tags: excel, vba

First i'm sorry if the title seems confusing however i couldn't find a better way to explain it. So i have this code:

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Sheets("Máquinas").Select


With Lista2

.ColumnCount = 9
.ColumnWidths = "80;0;200;0;0;0;0;0;50"

.RowSource = Sheets("Máquinas").Range("A1:U300").Address

End With


Sheets("Programa").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

I have a userform (let's call it form1) where i register something. However there is a list of potential variables that the user might want to consult before registering something in that form1. Therefore i have a command button in that userform that calls the userform2 (let's call it form2. The code above is from the form2). This form2 shows specific parts of a table that i have where the variables are stated (i think it's a listbox or something, basically a blank square that gets filled with the information when i run the code). My question is,is it possible to arrange some kind of interaction where when the user clicks or double clicks the parameter inside the form 2 it is automatically copied to a textbox in the form1?

Answer (score 0):

In form2 add this

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
If Me.ListBox1.ListIndex > -1 Then
   UserForm1.Controls("Textbox1").Value = Me.ListBox1.Column(2)

End If
End Sub
```

This assumes the listbox is named Listbox1, the first userform is named UserForm1 and the textbox is called Textbox1. This gets the value of the second column when you click on the list box and puts it into the textbox in the other form